# API authontication problem in android studio

Tags: java, api, android-studio, api-key

I am a beginner in Android Studio - Java .. I am working on Android App showing a car animation as Uber, I faced a problem when I tried to run a car animation in the emulator the url shows

```
   "error_message" : "You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs. For additional information, please refer to http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account",
   "routes" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

I create an API account and I activate the billing account. Also I restrict the API key to API Direction..

My code..

```
 requestUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?"+
                   "mode=driving&"+
                   "transit_routing_preference=less_driving&"+"origin=-33.92873%2C18.458879&destination=-33.92873%2C18.458879&waypoints=-33.9403%2C18.666731"+
                   "key="+getResources().getString(R.string.google_directions_key);

            Log.d("URL",requestUrl);//Print url to review by Chrome
            Log.d("The destination is : ", destination);
```

Also I used ( the Server key (auto created by Firebase)) ..

I search and try to solve this problem but I could not, all the solutions give me same result .. 
Can you hep me to solve this issue? 
Thank you ..

Comment: Did you enter your API key in `google_directions_key`?

Comment: Yes and I changed the API many times but does not work till now

Comment: I don't know if this also a problem or not (in run) 
`E/Volley: [5815] bq.a: Unexpected response code 400 for https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap/api
D/URL: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?mode=driving&transit_routing_preference=less_driving&origin=-33.92873%2C18.458879&destination=-33.92873%2C18.458879&waypoints=-33.9403%2C18.666731key=AIz`

Comment: have you fight this problem ?